# How to Publish Website (Web Forms) to Azure using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, webforms

How to publish your website on Azure . I developed my site in Web Forms using VS 2010 and i want to publish it on Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of documentation available. One method for example is to use the Azure management portal UI:

```
Example:

1. Go to the management portal for Windows Azure (WindowsAzure.com).

2. Create a new web site (see below).

3. Click on the web site to manage and configure it.

4. The manage and configure (dashboard) page is as below.

5. Focus on the quick glance section. Go ahead and create the deployment
   credentials (orange highlight). You will have to provide user name and password.

6. Copy the FTP Hostname and paste it in windows explorer (black
   highlight). In the pop-up window provide the user name and password
   for deployment. Note: the user name has to be given as “DOMAIN\USER”.        
   The DOMAIN is the web site name that you gave in step 4 above. In my 
   case it’s “TestAzureWS\phani_tpk”. (see blue highlight).

7. Folder navigation -> Click on Site, then click on wwwroot.

8. Copy the contents from step 2 above to this folder.
```

References:

- How to: Migrate and Publish a Web Application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service/
- Deploying Windows Azure Website using Visual Studio Web Publish wizard
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/26/deploying-windows-azure-website-using-visual-studio-web-publish-wizard.aspx
- Deploying to Windows Azure Web Sites Using FTP
  http://allthingsazure.com/deploying-to-windows-azure-web-sites-using-ftp/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While I agree with you in principle that URL resources change I would add that Microsoft are particular good at referencing old links to the new resource so there is always a path to the relevant information. Thanks for the feedback. Scott.